# An almost-uniform distribution over the Naturals. Does it have a name?

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology

I've just discovered this distribution, which is almost uniform over the naturals.  Surely I'm not the first to discover it?  Is it interesting?  Does it have a name?

$ \mathrm{P}(K = k) = \frac1k \frac1{k+1} $

I say 'almost uniform' because the ratio of probabilities of two consecutive integers approaches 1 for large $k$:

$ \frac{\mathrm{P}(K=k+1)}{\mathrm{P}(K=k)} = \frac{k}{k+2} $

This cumulative expression is probably the easiest place to start playing with it:

$ \mathrm{P}(K > k) = \frac1{k+1} $

I've Googled a little, but often end up with overly technical things I don't understand, such as [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.cmu.edu%2Ftr%2Ftr814%2Ftr814.pdf&ei=8shmUf4Qw8A819SAoA4&usg=AFQjCNHpP03G6jvC8pEnH8Li_L0JX7RYug&sig2=NR4pd7U05I_hJSQcg5QQ7Q&bvm=bv.45107431,d.ZWU), that seem to be tackling a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a particular case (parameter $\rho=1$) of the family of distributions called the [Yule–Simon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yule%E2%80%93Simon_distribution) distribution